# Don’t all the prepositional phrases modify words?

Tags: sentence-meaning, prepositional-phrases

I don't think “because of (something)” or “when it comes to (something)” modify words, although they are prepositional phrases.

For example, "*I didn’t do homework because of health.*" It just means I **didn’t** do homework and it’s because of health. (It can’t mean I did homework.)

Unlike this, for example, "*I didn’t do homework on Monday.*" It can mean I **did** homework on the other day.

Comment: "I didn't do my homework because I was ill." This must refer to the homework set for a particular day or days, so it is no different from "I didn't do my homework on Monday".

Comment: @Kate Bunting What I’m asking about is “I didn’t do my homework because I was ill/because of illness” means only that I didn’t do my homework. “I didn’t do my homework on Monday” can mean I did my homework anyway.

Comment: Only if you add "...but I did it on Tuesday instead" or similar.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I think I’ve misunderstood, thank you!

Comment: Context is king. "I didn't to my homework because I was sick" will always be interpreted to mean "I didn't to my homework", but could be parsed to mean, "I did my homework for some reason other than being sick". Nobody would infer that because *it's nonsense*, not because of any rule of grammar.

Comment: Also, I'm only guessing this is your question because your title and your first sentence contradict each other, and neither has much meaning.